# Accidental mark for delete - entire depot and reverting - perforce ..How to remove that tag(Mark for delete) from all files

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

Whole workspace files marked as delete in local also and depot also.
Depot contains thousands of file ..While reverting file options P4 get's hanged..
Any Solution for this ...help me...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When P4V hangs on these mass commands, I prefer using the command-line. In this case, `p4 revert //depot/path/to/the/workspace/...`.

Make sure you don't actually revert things you want to keep though.

Comment: p4 revert //depot/path/to/the/workspace/.... by using this command are you sure it won't get hanged because workspace have thousands of files ...

Comment: The command line is way more efficient for large data sets so it shouldn't hang.  If it does, hit Ctrl-C and break it up into smaller pieces.